# Android Studio cannot resolve method requestLocationUpdates FusedLocationProviderAPI

Tags: android

Everything is working except for this line: `LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);`

It's throwing a `cannot resolve method requestLocationUpdates` error. I don't see anything in the documentation, but I'm pretty new to Android so might be missing something.

Here's the full code. Any ideas where I'm going wrong? Thanks!

```
package com.example.alham.location;

import android.location.Location;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener{

    private final String LOG_TAG ="LaurenceTestApp";
    private TextView txtOutput;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();
        txtOutput = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtOutput);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart(){
        super.onStart();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop(){
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle){
        mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000);

        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location){
        Log.i(LOG_TAG,location.toString());
        txtOutput.setText(Double.toString(location.getLatitude()));
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i){
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "GoogleApiClient connection has been suspended");
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult){
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "GoogleApiClient connection has failed");
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you added **Google Play Services** dependency in your gradle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this in manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

and this in code:

```
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
                mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, new LocationListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                        // Here you have the updated location
                    }
                });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to check location permission is granted or not for Marshmallow and later version.

Make it like,

```
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
            googleApiClient, locationRequest, this);
```